# Save Image Object VueJS

Tags: javascript, image, api, file, vue.js

I have an Image Object in VueJS as `File {name: "myFile.png", webkitRelativePath: "", size: 120124, …}`.
I want to save this image into one of my folders.
How can I do this in VueJS?

*One more question:* Should I save user images to either front-end or back-end?
I can send a request to back-end API but if images are on front-end side it may work fast *(correct me if I'm wrong).*

> **Note:** My front-end *(VueJS)* and back-end *(Laravel as API)* are separate projects.

Comment: I assume that you want to save the images on your server i.e. where you backend is? Or are you wanting to save it to the clients machine?

Comment: I have front-end VueJS and I want to save it into one of the folders like **assets**. Is that possible or I must store it into backend?

Comment: Yeah, this will only be possible with the backend as you'll have to send the file to the server.

Comment: You could save files to google drive instead, then you wouldn't need a backend, only the google drive api

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an api endpoint on the backend for file saving. On a frontend you have to send POST request with attached file.

```
(picture) => {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('picture', picture);
  return fetch(
    `${this.$dishApi}/recipes/${recipeId}/pictures/`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem(this.$dishApiTokenKey),
      },
      body: data,
    },
  )
    .then(
      (res) => res.json(),
    );
},
```

This function taken from vue component. Here FormData object created to store files from the user form. You can append several files in this way.

After appending files post request sent with FormData object inside.